# The symmetry line in the middle of the 3D models In unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, normals, uv-mapping, 3d-model

First of all , this image is my 3d model that I imported into unity3d :

[image]

Why this happening ?

In **MAYA** software this line is not appear but when I import this model into unity3d , the model seems like the above image.

what I guessing is , my 3d model UVs are overlapping together , and because of saving the texture size and getting better quality I set them like this image :

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this issue in Unity3D without changing the UV's ?

Comment: My guess is that the two polygons either side of the center line are either: (1) not welded together or (2) the normals along that edge aren't set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the line results from the models phong setting.
You can try to overwrite it in the `Import Settings` of the model: Just play around with the `Smoothing Angle`. Perhaps you have to adjust the `Smoothness Source` too.

[image]